# add dynamic (no matter image size) shadow effect on images?

Tags: php, image

Is it possible to create a 1 pixel shadow image (say shadow.jpg) in photoshop, and then with PHP repeat that shadow just beneath or on the side of an image, for whatever the width or height of the target image is?

Example: If my image is 640x420 then shadow.jpg will be repeated just beneath this image 640 times, thus creating a drop shadow effect!

Is this a good method?

If not, what other options are there to achieve the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to create a new image, or to style it inside of an HTML page?

Comment: Style an existing image on the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to style the image for display on the web, and not actually creating a new image using GD/etc.  You could look into one of many [CSS Drop Shadow](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=2kD&q=css+drop+shadow&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g-p1g9) Techniques.

- [One Method](http://www.wubbleyew.com/tests/dropshadows.htm)
- [Another Method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdropshadows/)
- [A few more methods](http://phoenity.com/newtedge/drop_shadow/)

CSS3 is bringing [very nice shadow effects](http://www.zenelements.co.uk/blog/css3-shadows-border-image-text/) to current browsers if you don't mind the content degrading in unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for doing it in CSS.

http://www.wubbleyew.com/tests/dropshadows.htm